# Javascript multi-dependent drop-down menu not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have managed to manipulate existing code to make a 5 tier multi dependent drop down menu form, and it works well. The only problem is I need the same drop down menu system over and over again up to maybe 8 rows.

Although the drop down menu system looks like it is working well and it does on the 1st row there is a glitch on the second row. When you go back one level to the previous dropdown menu and choose another option, instead of the next drop down resetting with the new options it just adds to it and the more you do this the longer the drop down menu grows!

Here is my code:

In HTML Header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="5level2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="5level22.js"></script>
```

In HTML Body

```
<form name="tripleplay">
<p align="center">
<select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List2' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List3' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List4']), getValue(this.value, this.form['List2'].value, 
this.form['List1'].value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List4' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List5']), getValue(this.value, this.form['List3'].value, 
this.form['List2'].value, this.form['List1'].value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List5' onchange="getValue(this.value, this.form['List4'].value, 
this.form['List3'].value, this.form['List2'].value), this.form['List1'].value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="T1" size="10">
<input type="text" name="T2" size="4"></p>
<p align="center">
<select name='List6' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List7'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List7' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List8'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List8' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List9']), getValue(this.value, this.form['List7'].value, 
this.form['List6'].value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List9' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List10']), getValue(this.value, this.form['List8'].value, 
this.form['List7'].value, this.form['List6'].value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List10' onchange="getValue(this.value, this.form['List9'].value, 
this.form['List8'].value, this.form['List7'].value), this.form['List6'].value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="T3" size="10">
<input type="text" name="T4" size="4"></p>
<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

Here is the script code in 5level2.js

```
var categories = [];
categories["startList"] = ["England","Spain"]
categories["England"] = ["Premiership"];
categories["Spain"] = ["LaLiga"];
categories["Premiership"] = ["Arsenal","Chelsea"];
categories["LaLiga"] = ["Barca","Madrid"];
categories["Arsenal"] = ["Arsenal Current","Arsenal Legends"];
categories["Chelsea"] = ["Chelsea Current","Chelsea Legends"];
categories["Barca"] = ["Barca Current","Barca Legends"];
categories["Madrid"] = ["Madrid Current","Madrid Legends"];
categories["Arsenal Current"] = ["Sanchez","Ozil"];
categories["Arsenal Legends"] = ["Henry","Begkamp"];
categories["Chelsea Current"] = ["Hazard","Willian"];
categories["Chelsea Legends"] = ["Terry","Lampard"];
categories["Barca Current"] = ["Messi","Suarez"];
categories["Barca Legends"] = ["Xavi","Puyol"];
categories["Madrid Current"] = ["Ronaldo","Bale"];
categories["Madrid Legends"] = ["Figo","Zidane"];

var nLists = 5; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
for (each in nCat) {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
}

function init() {
fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

Here is script code for 5level22.js

```
var categories = [];
categories["startList"] = ["England","Spain"]
categories["England"] = ["Premiership"];
categories["Spain"] = ["LaLiga"];
categories["Premiership"] = ["Arsenal","Chelsea"];
categories["LaLiga"] = ["Barca","Madrid"];
categories["Arsenal"] = ["Arsenal Current","Arsenal Legends"];
categories["Chelsea"] = ["Chelsea Current","Chelsea Legends"];
categories["Barca"] = ["Barca Current","Barca Legends"];
categories["Madrid"] = ["Madrid Current","Madrid Legends"];
categories["Arsenal Current"] = ["Sanchez","Ozil"];
categories["Arsenal Legends"] = ["Henry","Begkamp"];
categories["Chelsea Current"] = ["Hazard","Willian"];
categories["Chelsea Legends"] = ["Terry","Lampard"];
categories["Barca Current"] = ["Messi","Suarez"];
categories["Barca Legends"] = ["Xavi","Puyol"];
categories["Madrid Current"] = ["Ronaldo","Bale"];
categories["Madrid Legends"] = ["Figo","Zidane"];

var nLists = 5; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
for (each in nCat) {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
}

function init() {
fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List6'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

Only difference is the string with the 'startList' has changed from List1 to List6.

I initially thought I may have different options in the drop down menus but it may no longer be needed so just one .js file will do with just one list of variables.

Comment: can you please show us some working demo?

Comment: Working demo: http://www.pcreload.co.uk/dropdown.htm